# Delete hash field if it is a specific value

Tags: lua, redis

I want to loop through all hashes that match a pattern, and then delete a field if it is equal to a certain value.

```
keys UserProfile-*
```

If the hash has a field named "usercount" I want to delete it.

I was reading that I can delete a field like this:

```
if redis.call("HEXISTS", KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == 1 then
  return redis.call("HINCRBY", KEYS[1], ARGV[1], 1)
else
  return nil
end
```

But I need to loop through all keys that match a pattern, and then somehow pass those values along to delete them if they exist.

Comment: You use HDEL to delete a field in a hash, HINCRBY will just increment the number stored under that field. Which bit are you having problems with?

Comment: You're reading something that's totally wrong. The script deletes nothing